# Drupal7 Feeds module Facebook feed truncated to 80 characters

Tags: facebook, drupal, rss, drupal-7

In Drupal 7, My Facebook feed is displayed in a View. The mapping is set for title to title and body to body. But the Facebook post is getting truncated at80 characters followed by (...)  example: EmC’s Direct-Hire Construction team was recently honored for achieving more tha...

i mapped a bunch of items to the Body but still doesn't show the whole paragraph? The view and CCk type is set up to display the full node and not the teaser. Should I use a Parser or add a embed field? My Flickr feed is doing the same thing. I am using the Drupal 7 and the Feeds module. My Youtube and Twitter feeds work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open your database and check body fields of this content type - if it consist from 80 char, the problem in creating field from feed (maybe that's some nuance of facebook api).
if body consists of more than 80 char - you have the problem with views setting, maybe it's adjusted to show body field like teaser or limited to 80 characters.